# EJB entities: Best way to update a single column

Tags: java, ejb

Using EJB entities, I need to update a single column of a single row in a 100+ columns table. I usually read/load the row and make necessary updates, but that seems overwhelming as all remaining columns will be updated unnecessarily, not to mention the performance penalty. 
Is there a way to *just* update the single column similar to the traditional JDBC way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute an update query:

```
update Foo f set f.someField = :someValue where f.id = :id
```

Be aware though that this change won't be reflected in the entity if it's already loaded, and that it will bypass optimistic locking. 
Make sure not to optimize prematurely. If simply modifying the entity is fast enough, then just do that.

I would rather feel concerned about having an entity with more than 100 fields. Maybe you should split that into several entities.

Comment: thanks for your answer. when you say `this change won't be reflected in the entity if its already loaded` it means that if the entity is already loaded and I perform a `find` the field that I updated will have the old value?

Comment: So the way to go seems to perform the find and then update the entity instead of running the update directly

Comment: No, exactly the inverse. If you do that, you will have a loaded entity that will contain an obsolete value. Whereas if you update first and then get the entity from the database, you'll get the updated value in the entity.

Comment: don't I need to load the entity first to do an update? I first do `find` to get the entity, then change any attributes and then do `merge`

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Your question asked: how do I update a single column without updating all the fields of an entity. I answered by saying that, instead of loading the entity and modifying it, you can use an update query. And then you're saying that what you intend to do is load the entity and update it, causing all the fields to be updated. If that's what you intend to do anyway, why did you ask the question?

Comment: You told me that using the update query has a problem, that's why I said `the way to go seems not to use the update query`

Comment: It doesn't have a problem. You just need to be aware of what it does and what it doesn't, and code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use JPA, first you can query the record entity need to be updated,and modify the properties of this entity. Then invoke the EntityManager to update this entity. thus you just update one record which you want to update.